# OS X: why Software Update suggests to update removed application?

Tags: macos, updates

I have a small OS X 10.5 installation for testing purposes (otherwise use 10.6). After I switched to 10.5 today, *Software Update* told me that there is a new update available for *iTunes*. But I have trashed *iTunes* a long time ago (it's not listed any more if I open `/Applications`) and purged the trash. Why then OS X will suggest me to update it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you "uninstalled" iTunes, did you just drag /Applications/iTunes.app to the Trash? Completely removing iTunes from your machine is a bit more involved than that.

Apple provides step-by-step instructions for removing iTunes from Mac OS X here: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1224. Try following these instructions first, and then check Software Update again.