# Remove iTunes on Mac OS X permanently: no Software Update

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, itunes, updates

Somewhat predictably, removing iTunes on Mac OS X is a long arduous process, described at http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1224 — which I have followed. As far as I can tell, I have purged every trace of the accursed iTunes from my system. Yet Software Update repeatedly prompts me with updates for iTunes, which I don't want anything to do with, despite my saying "Not now" each time. How can I convince Software Update to leave me alone, and never bother me with mention of iTunes again?

I'm on Mac OS X 10.6.4 Build 10F569, and the update being offerred is iTunes 9.2.1.

(Note: Not a duplicate of [OS X: why Software Update suggests to update removed application?](https://superuser.com/questions/170544/os-x-why-software-update-suggests-to-update-removed-application), whose accepted answer is simply to follow the instructions I mentioned above.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the Software Update app pops up, go to Update > Ignore Update, and you shouldn't get prompted anymore.

Comment: Ah that worked, thanks. Don't know why I never noticed that thing there.

Comment: that seems to be not working on Yosemite. There's simply no "Ignore update" button